# Get Hour and minute from time string

Tags: php, date

I have response from an API like below

```
2019-05-08T10:36:00+0530
```

I want to take `10:36` from it, right now I do something with regex like

```
preg_match('/T(.*?)\:00/');
```

It works, but is there any other actual way to do it more efficiently? That works on any time string in this format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a DateTime object by passing that string into the constructor and just format it to your liking with `format()`! You might want `H:i` if you just want the hours and minutes, or `H:i:s` if you want to include the seconds.

```php
$string = "2019-05-08T10:36:00+0530";
$date = new DateTime($string);
echo $date->format("H:i:s");
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/BmnoU

Answer (score 0):

If your string format is fixed, you can use [substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

```
$string = "2019-05-08T10:36:00+0530";
echo substr($string, 11, 5);
```

**Output:**

```
10:36
```

[Working Example:](https://3v4l.org/vkrAe)